# Adding one widget on top of another

Tags: c++, qt, overlap, qwidget

I'd like to set a `layout` where I have a `QTableWidget` and a semi-transparent `QLabel` rendered on top of it, that way the table will appear through the semi opaque `QLabel` image (`png`).

I've tried using a `QBoxLayout`:

```
QWidget* centralWidget = new QWidget;
QBoxLayout* layout = new QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout::TopToBottom, NULL);
QTableWidget* table = new QTableWidget(3, 3);
table->setFixedSize(400, 400);
table->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
QLabel* pLabel = new QLabel;
QPixmap pix("./Frame_transp4.png");
pLabel->setPixmap(pix);
layout->addWidget(table);
layout->addWidget(pLabel);
centralWidget->setLayout(layout);
MainWnd.setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
```

Current result:

[image: label at the bottom of a table widget]

Desired result:

[image: Label on top of table widget]

I also tried `QStackedLayout`, but it does not seem to work because it allows to render only one widget at a time.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have a look at [`QGridLayout`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html).

Comment: ...or [`QStackedLayout`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedlayout.html).

Comment: If you're using `QStackedLayout` you need to use [`setStackingMode(QStackedLayout::StackAll)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedlayout.html#stackingMode-prop).

Comment: Or create the QLabel with the `centralWidget` as parent *without* adding it to the layout, then manually set its geometry.

Comment: If that label is supposed to decorate the frame of the table widget, I suggest you mention that as context; you might get better approaches suggested to achieve that goal.